# Zero object in a category: example explanation

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to understand the definition of zero object in a category. Here is some para from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_object_(algebra)), which I am confused at one point, while looking by an example. Wikipedia says,

> The $\{0\}$ object is a terminal object of any algebraic structure where it exists, like it was described for examples above. But its existence and, if it exists, the property to be an initial object (and hence, a zero object in the category-theoretical sense) depend on exact definition of the multiplicative identity 1 in a specified structure.
> If the definition of $1$ requires that $1\neq 0$, then the $\{0\}$ object cannot exist because it may contain only one element.

**Question:** Consider the category of algebras over the field $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers. Certainly, $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is there; and as singleton matrix of zero entries, the subalgebra $\{ 0_{n}\}$ is there. Also, in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ (or even in $\mathbb{R}$), we have $1\neq 0$. Then, the last statement in above quoted para is confusing me; can one explain it?

Comment: In the subalgebra that consists only of $0_n$ doesn't $1=0$ actually hold?

Comment: Note that the mentioned quote is not about categories, but about algebraic structures, such as groups, rings, field, vector fields and such. Here the above says: If we have a Ring-like structure the $\{0\}$ substructure cannot exist if we demand in definition that $1\neq0$ (which is quite obvious, as such a structure needs at least two elements).